# Is Visual Studio Code's PHP debug console interactive?

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.16.1 together with Felix Becker's [PHP Debug extension](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug). I'm connecting to XDebug just fine, can set breakpoints and view variables in the debug pane without any issues.

However, the debug console seems kind of useless, I can only run super basic PHP commands, and I can't seem to evaluate normal PHP commands or interact with my app very well.

I consistently get `error evaluating code` when attempting to type any PHP statements or expressions in the debug console. It seems like all I am able to do is declare variables, arrays, and objects.

I can't declare classes, functions, use control structures (`if`, `foreach`, etc.).

**Works:**

```
$x = 4
//4

$x
//4

$x = new stdClass();
//stdClass

$x = [];
//array(0)

($x) ? yes : no
// yes

(!$x) ? yes : no
// no

preg_replace('/dog/', 'cat', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')
// "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cat."

request()
//Illuminate\Http\Request (Laravel helper methods work)
```

**Doesn't Work:**

```
echo "yes"
//error evaluating code

if ($x == 4) { echo "yes" }
//error evaluating code

for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { }
//error evaluating code

function foo() {}
//error evaluating code

class SimpleClass {}
//error evaluating code

$var_dump($x)
//null
```

Is the debug console supposed to act like a true REPL? I know PHPStorm's console can evaluate any PHP you throw at it, can Visual Studio Code do the same? Is anyone else facing this problem?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: update: I learned that `var_dump` reports an error to the console, but spits output to the browser instead (when using "Listen for XDebug" mode)

Comment: update 2: the extension developer says this has nothing to do with the PHP Debug extension, this is all on the xdebug side: https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug/issues/192

Comment: update 3: according to the dev, this is how it is supposed work: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1476. Declaring classes and functions do not return a value. And `echo` and `var_dump` send their output to the browser, not to STDOUT. Anyways, in my debug workflow I've learned to not use the console. I just watch variables in the debug panel, and update and refresh my code in the normal editor window.

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP Storm provides a much better experience when developing in PHP :/

Comment: My experience is similar to yours: you can do some basic stuff in the console like evaluating vars in scope, but I don't think you can use more complicated statements nor define/change values

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** It's an XDebug related issue, not related to OP's extension, and canceling the watch variables may fix XDebug behaviour.

---

The issue is not related to OP's extension, it's an XDebug related issue.

Many people workaround this issue, by removing the variables from VSCode's "Watch" list, in the debug view.

In following screenshot, the red arrow indicates a button where you can delete all watch-expressions with once click:

[image: VSCode's watch variable section]

See also: [github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/192](https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/192)

Answer (score -1):

You are limited to what is actual debugging. It' useful to interact with an active program to fix it, not as a playground like in a Python or a Javascript console. I you want to create some scripts, create a PHP CLI file.

You should use print instead of echo and var_dump() not $var_dump(). Then it depends if you are in CLI mode or in FPM mode (web-server). If you are connected to a web server in a debugging session, it will not print back into the debugger terminal but into the web server response.

Comment: I can confirm that for some strange reason `print` does seem to work. It always returns 1 to the debug console and sends the string to the web-server. If you want to print to the debug console, you may want to try `print_r($variable, true);` as it returns arrays properly formatted and makes easier understand the content of a variable or the value returned by a function.